# How to reload an activity once when it open

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to go from `Activity1` to `Activity1` (with newly loaded data), but the problem is that when I use `recreate();` in `onCreate();` the activity just keeps reloading and reloading till the program crashes.

So is there anyway to make the activity reload one time when its opened (By `onCreate` and `onResume`).

> **Clarification**: I need to reload the activity to get the new data from a web service (due to a problem that caused the old data to show instead of the new ones) so the only way this will work is by reloading my activity.

Comment: so why not u direct get the new data when the activity created?

Comment: I do but an error happens that causes the old data show and when I reload the activity (manually) everything seems good.

Comment: You can check the data in pause's state

Comment: so why not u call the web service again,why u get the old data?

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag variable inside your activity ("Instance Variable")
`var mIsInitialLoad = true`
, then In whatever lifecycle method or function inside your activity:

```
if (mIsInitialLoad) {
  recreate()
  mIsInitialLoad = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link

[Lifecycle State (Android Developers Site)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State)

Example

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    // Call Method to check data
}


package com.note.principal

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import com.note.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        // Check the data when activity is starting
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        // Check the data when activity finishes
    }
}
```